# Trying to send requests from a Heroku dyno results in a connection error in python discord bots

Tags: python, heroku, discord, hosting, discord.py

I have a bot which is retrieving information from a website online. When I run it normally or use [`repl.it`](https://repl.it) the request goes through. However, I recently switched the bot over to heroku. Now it gives me a connection error.

```py
import aiohttp
import discord
import asyncio

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
    async with s.get('https://mcuuid.net/?q=' + playername) as r:
        if r.status == 200:
            html = await r.text()
            ending = html.split('<input id="results_id" class="form-control click-select" readonly="readonly" value="')[1]
            UUID = ending.split('"></td></tr><tr><td><label for="results_raw_id">Trimmed UUID</label></td><td><in')[0]

            if UUID == "":
                await stext(msg, "No minecraft account found.")
                return
            else:
                await stext(msg, "Connection error. ")
                return
```

This is one snippet of the code I am using. I know my code works as using it on a different hosting service works. A [connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXVWw.png) occurs on discord. I am wondering if Heroku blocks requests like pythonanywhere does. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are probably getting HTTP 403 Access denied. A lot of websites have Heroku servers on the block list because there are a lot of people who spam their servers with requests. Some don't error handle the requests and then thousands of requests are being sent out. You can try to rehost under a different dyno hoping on getting an IP that is not blocked or use a different service.

Comment: Thanks! I also recently found a different website which does the same thing and has not blocked requests from heroku. (sk1er.club)